# video plays only in mplayer but not in other players

Tags: video, ubuntu-11.04

mplayer plays video with audio but vlc, totem players plays only audio. Tried reinstalling nvidia drivers, restricted-extras package, etc. I cant figure out how to troubleshoot

Comment: This may have to do with codecs... What file format are the video's you're playing in?

Answer (score 0):

You could find the used codecs of your `FILE` by typing

```
mplayer -frames 0 -identify FILE
```

Then search the net, if your desired players support those codecs. Or ask here.